# How to set expires in Mongoose 5.12.5 to expire at 20 days?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

'm trying to create an autoexpire after 20 days in mongoose with express but not working for me: "express": "^4.17.1", "mongoose": "^5.12.5"

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

const postSchema = new Schema(
  {
    expireAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now, index: { expires: "20d" } },

    title: { type: String, trim: true, default: null },

    imgURL: { type: String, default: null },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionkey: false,
  }
);

export default model("Post", postSchema);
```

¿can you help me? after 20 days mongoose does not delete the posts I have created.

If this version of mongoose doesn't work for this, please tell me which version is appropriate

Thanks :)!

Answer (score 1):

try this : expireAt : { type: Date, default: Date.now, expires: '20d' }